# How to get a total days count

Tags: mysql

Using MySQL & SQL Server

```
ID sDate

001 03/06/2010
002 07/08/2010
....
....
```

sDate Datatype is varchar
Format mm/dd/yyyy

I want to take the date count means How many days is still there, It should compare the system date...

How to convert my varchar to datetime datatype, then how to compare the mysdate to system for getting the totalday counts

```
sDate - SystemDate = Totalday
```

ExpectedOutput

```
ID sDate Totaldays

001 03/07/2010 3 days
002 07/07/2010 7 days
.....
```

How to make a query for this condition. Need query help.

Comment: You may want to consider changing your datatype to an actual date type.  When using any built-in MySQL DATE functions there will a type conversion every time, which can lead to really poor performance.

Comment: retagged as it seems the question has nothing to do with mysql

Comment: okay. change your silly date format to the proper one.

Comment: It seems, there is no convert date query in mysql

Comment: You can use your server side language to reformat the dates already in database.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your question states MySQL & SQL Server so here is both:

SQL Server [datediff](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258269%28SQL.80%29.aspx) function:

```
SELECT ID, DATEDIFF(DAY, GETDATE(), CONVERT(DATETIME, sDate)) FROM TABLE
```

MySQL [datediff](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) function:

```
SELECT ID, DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), STR_TO_DATE(sDate, '%c/%d/%Y')) FROM TABLE
```

This uses the [STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function to convert the varchar to a date and assumes that the format of your date strings is in the format month/day/year.

Comment: When i run the above query in mysql,  it is showing error as "you have an error in sqlserver syntax; check the manual that correspond to your mysql server version for the right syntax to use near sdate from table" – Gopal 10 mins ago

Comment: How to convert varchar to datetime in mysql, because output is showing null value.....

Comment: Hi @Gopal, I have changed the example to use STR_TO_DATE to convert the sDate varchar to a date.

Answer (score 0):

Gopal, in response to your "How to convert varchar to datetime in mysql...", it's easy:

```
ALTER TABLE sometable CHANGE sDate sDate datetime;
```

and MySQL will happily attempt to convert the values for you. However, if it can't properly parse the original date string, that record's sDate will get set to `NULL` or `0000-00-00`. You'll have to massage the sDate field first to convert it to a more normal MySQL format for date strings, which is YYYY-MM-DD. A bruteforce hack would be:

```
UPDATE sometable SET sDate=CONCAT(
   SUBSTR(sDate, 6, 4),
   '/',
   SUBSTR(sDate, 3, 2),
   '/',
   SUBSTR(sDate, 0, 2)
);
```

Of course, this is assuming that your dates are in DD/MM/YYYY format. If they're MM/DD/YYYY, then just swap the middle and last SUBSTR calls. Once this update's completed, then you can use the ALTER TABLE to change field types.

And of course, for anything that affects the entire table like this, make sure you have a backup of it first.